# non-trademarked name for Toslink connector?

Tags: spdif

My PC motherboard has header pins for a SPDIF output and I want to an optical SPDIF transmitter.

When I search any of the main electronic stores for optical SPDIF transmitter I dont get any good hits, I can find some if I search Toslink transmitter, but these are very expensive and all Toshiba branded.
I assume there must be some generic optical SPDIF transmitters, but I dont know what to search for.
Does anyone know?

Comment: the question is about the correct name for a part, nothing to do with shopping.

Comment: I don't have any trouble finding SPDIF "cards" for PCs. Maybe play with your search terms.

Comment: FWIW Broadcom (aka Avago) also makes TOSLINK components. I don't know whether you'd consider them "very expensive" or not.

Comment: @thephoton are they also labelled as TOSLINK?

Comment: @Jay, yes, they are.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The 'card' is already there, it's built into the motherboard, but the SPDIF output is just a pin header, its needs a transmitter to get optical output.

Comment: Yes, what I'm talking about has three wires that go to a pin header.

Comment: @thePhoton ok, I didn't notice any Broadcom ones when searching for TOSLINK but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Ok , I see what you mean, just the coax and optical output connectors in pci bracket, they are pretty inexpensive too. They are even cheaper than just the TOSLINK transmitters, I still wonder if this card is also using Toshiba parts or if there is some other manufacturers who is making a cheaper copy

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia entry for TOSLINK says that the ADAT Lightpipe and TOSLINK formats, though incompatible with each other, both use the JIS F05 connector.